# Reducing partition in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I cant seem to reduce my c:\ drive with more than 41gb.
The partition has 650gb free space, and i am trying to turn 200gb into unallocated space for an ubuntu partition.
I use the windows partition manager, and i have tried to do a defrag without any result

Comment: I can only find questions asking how to reduce the partition. I have 650gb free but can only reduce by 41gb. could you point me to an answer if this is a duplicate? I might use some wrong serachwords

Comment: okay, saw the answer at the top... sorry, new to the site ;)